# Redis and Rails counter cache column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I currently use a counter cache column in Rails, but I'm starting to perform more complicated queries on the association (ratings). For performance reasons, I'm moving the data into Redis.

My question is, are counter cache columns still relevant when storing all of the data in Redis, or will Redis make this approach obsolete (and just perform count on Redis store)?

I guess it comes down to:

```
post.ratings_count # cache_column, table in sql database
$redis.scard("post:123:ratings")
```

Course, the `post.ratings_count` will simply fetch an attribute, not perform a query (as post will already be loaded). My only concern is that `$redis.scard` will perform some kind of 'query' on the Redis store. Is it negligible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be worried about SCARD command performances.

redis SCARD command has time complexity O(1) this means it has pretty much no cost for redis to do it.

If you can afford to store the full set in redis then  is not that useful anymore to have a cached count.

Unfortunately you dont always have enough space to store everything in redis (redis storage must fit in your ram) so in that case having a cached count column still makes sense.

Comment: @Tommaso Barbugi I'm new to Redis. If you said we suggestion to keep cached count, it means we still updating that column every time, so what's benefit having redis because when we load a post it will including a count field as well?